# Expected an UID followed by a ':' make: *** [Makefile:130 : compiler] Error 255

Tags: compiling, make, gnu

I was trying to build the Sather compiler, everything was going fine and I got this error with make :

```
Creating C for installation compiler...

Boot/sacomp     -verbose -O_fast -O_no_move_while -O_no_hoist_const -O_no_cse -only_reachable Compiler/sacomp.module -o Bin/sacomp -only_C
/usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3/System/Common/CONFIG:1:error, expected an UID followed by a ':'
make: *** [Makefile:130 : compiler] Erreur 255
```

This doesn't seem to be a dependency problem (and I think I installed them all).
Here is the whole output if it can help (sorry my computer is in french) :

```
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3/System/Common »
make[1]: rien à faire pour « all ».
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3/System/Common »

Making serial library: System Socket 
Containers 

Making platform BOOT...
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3/System/Platforms/BOOT »
make[1]: rien à faire pour « all ».
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3/System/Platforms/BOOT »
Making platform linux...
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3/System/Platforms/linux »
make[1]: rien à faire pour « all ».
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3/System/Platforms/linux »

Making boot compiler...

make -C System/Platforms/linux boot CC='gcc'
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3/System/Platforms/linux »
ln -sf `pwd`/header.h ../BOOT
make -C /usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3/Boot/sacomp.code CC=gcc
make[2] : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3/Boot/sacomp.code »
make[2]: « ../sacomp » est à jour.
make[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3/Boot/sacomp.code »
rm -f ../BOOT/header.h
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3/System/Platforms/linux »

Creating C for installation compiler...

Boot/sacomp     -verbose -O_fast -O_no_move_while -O_no_hoist_const -O_no_cse -only_reachable Compiler/sacomp.module -o Bin/sacomp -only_C
/usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3/System/Common/CONFIG:1:error, expected an UID followed by a ':'
make: *** [Makefile:130 : compiler] Erreur 255
```

Any help, or an easier way to install Sather on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that the sather System/Common/Makefile uses The C Preprocessor, `cpp` to preprocess CONFIG.proto into CONFIG. Since `cpp` does not know that the intended output is `sather` rather than `C`, it processes and inserts the standard header file /usr/include/stdc-predef.h at the start of the CONFIG file, as you can verify by doing

```
cpp -dI System/Common/CONFIG.proto | head
```

Because make variable `CPP` is defined in the top-level Makefile as `CPP=/lib/cpp -C -P`, comments in the input files are not suppressed. So the CONFIG file ends up with a big `/* C-style */` comment block at the top, which apparently chokes the `sather` parser (which apparently expects comments to start with `-`).

The inclusion of the stdc-predef.h seems to have been introduced in GCC 4.8, and the recommended way to enforce backward compatibility is with the option `-ffreestanding` (although this option does not appear to be documented in the cpp man page):

```
make clean
make CPP='cpp -ffreestanding -C -P'
```

You should then be able to execute `./Bin/sacomp` as follows

```
SATHER_HOME=. ./Bin/sacomp
There is no class named MAIN.
```

(presumably it expects to be given the name of one or more source files).

See [Porting to GCC 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/porting_to.html) .

Comment: thank you very much now make didn't show any errors. I was very happy until this happens when I run sacomp :
`Couldn't open file: /usr/lib/sather/System/Common/Common.module`
`Command line error near: /usr/lib/sather/System/Common/Common.module in command line`
`(See man page.)`
Do you have any advice?

Comment: Apparently there is no /usr/lib/sather at all. I guess it's because I installed it at the wrong place

Comment: I moved the sather folder to /usr/lib and now I get this (tried copy pasting sather to its original place) : `Couldn't open file: $(SATHER_HOME)/Library/System/Socket/Socket.module
Command line error near: -external in /usr/lib/sather/System/Platforms/linux/Platform.module
(See man page.)`

Comment: Executing `SATHER_HOME=. ./Bin/sacomp` from the `sather-1.2.3` directory seems to run for me (although it expects a source file - I don't know anything about this compiler)

Comment: ... in fact, the HTML installation instructions (at Doc/Installation.html) suggest setting `SATHER_HOME` **before** running `make`. In your case, that would be `export SATHER_HOME=/usr/local/src/sather-1.2.3` based on your choice of build location

Comment: I really thank you for taking the time to finds answers to find the answers to my problem. Actually I set the variable earlier but when running the correct `make CPP='cpp -ffreestanding -C -P'` I totally forgot. Now I'm getting `Internal compiler error: Couldn't write thumbprints` but the problem comes from the compiler and not from the build. Thanks again and I guess I'll just try another language lol

Comment: @Niout8 you're welcome - good luck!

Comment: I managed to make it work by installing it again in /usr/lib/sather instead of the previous. You made my day